# iOS zxing: no member named BarcodeFormat_AZTEC

Tags: ios, zxing

I'm having trouble getting the latest version of the ZXing library up and running. I've downloaded the latest source from http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/ and the ZXing 2.0 release from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

I've setup the folder structure like so:
project/iphone/ZXingWidget/ZXingWidget.xcodeproj
project/cpp/ios.xcodeproj

When I open up ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and build, I get an error in CBarcodeFormat.mm that there is "no member named 'BarcodeFormat_AZTEC' in namespace 'zxing'". However, if I look in CBarcodeFormat.h, there is definitely an item in the enum called BarcodeFormat_AZTEC.

I've also noticed there are some files missing from the project (they're red in the project navigator). Specifically, these files:
- CoreSrc/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.cpp
- CoreSrc/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.h
- CoreSrc/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGFPoly.cpp
- CoreSrc/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF.h
- CoreSrc/zxing/common/aztec/*

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?